# Template a virtual method from base class instead of use overloading

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inner-classes, virtual-functions

I got strange code and have to extend it. But instead of copy paste many many times i decided to create a template. But get caught by a terrible rock.

Here is an example code:

```
template<typename T>
class anyClass {};

template<typename T>
class Outer : public anyClass<T>
{
public:
   using value_t = T;
   class Inner
   {
      virtual void foo(value_t);
   };
};

class specializer : protected Outer::Inner
{
   virtual void foo(int) override {}
}
```

I have to extend `virtual void foo(value_t)` in specializer.

Example:

```
class specializer : protected Outer::Inner
{
   virtual void foo(int) override {}
   virtual void foo(float) override {}
   virtual void foo(string) override {}
   virtual void foo(bar) override {}
   // And so on...
 }
```

**Question 1: Why works the example, although `class specializer : protected Outer::Inner` miss a param?**

All overloadings do nearly the same. I created already the function.

```
template<typename anyType>
void meow( anyType )
{
/***/
}
```

My problem is here:

```
virtual void foo(anytype value) //<< replace anytype with what?
{
   meow<anytype>( value );
}
```

I need the type `Outer::value_T` but i don't know how to get it.

**Question 2: How can i use `meow` by calling `foo` ?**

Feel free to ask for more information.

**UPDATE**

I looked again in the origin code and realised, that i've overlooked an important using/typedef. 
The working code looks like:

```
class specializer : protected Outer<int, float, string, bar>::Inner //Yes a variadic-template
{
   virtual void foo(int) override {}
   virtual void foo(float) override {}
   virtual void foo(string) override {}
   virtual void foo(bar) override {}
   // And so on...
 }
```

So **Question 1 is solved**.

Comment: "class specializer : protected Outer::Inner" no such class Outer::Inner (the first letter is upper-case)

Comment: Also, there is no such class as `Outer::inner` either, because `Outer` is a template, not a class.

Comment: @user3514538 thanks, fixed that.

Comment: @user2079303 I agree with that. Thats the reason I'm confuse that the example code compile and works correctly (In originial form).

Comment: @Syrlia, it builds!? On what toolchain!? GCC rejects it, http://ideone.com/3RAEvF, and rightfully so.

Comment: An offtopic question. I got new info. Should i append these or rewrite the question?

Comment: I have never seen protected inheritance in practice and the common wisdom is that it only exists for completeness because we have public and private inheritance. Could you explain why you use it here?

Comment: Why not? If someone want to inherit the specialiser he could use the Base class.  Isn't there a rule: "Be Open To Change"?

Comment: @Syrlia That's the Open-Closed-Principle. There are better ways to achieve that. I am drafting an answer to show an alternative design, but I am not sure if it matches your problem. Anyway, my question is more why you choose protected inheritance and not public or private.

Comment: Your update shouldn't compile either as it stands. Not with the original code snippet. Either `Outer` is a variadic class template, or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Why works the example, although class specializer : protected Outer::Inner miss a param?

The example [does *not* work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e2865b2d5c3f48e). It does not work because `Outer` is not a type. Also, you override multiple overloads of `foo` even though `inner` has only one `foo`. There are several syntax errors too. *If* it appears to work, then the compiler is doing something non-standard.

About your second question:

```
virtual void foo(anytype value) //<< replace anytype with what?
```

You replace it with the type whose overload you intend to override. For example, if you intend to override `foo(int)`, then replace `anytype` with `int`.

> Question 2: How can i use meow by calling foo ?

Simply call `meow` in `foo`.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I detect a hidden variadic behind a typedef in the code and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make `specializer` a template class.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void meow(T x) 
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
class anyClass {};

template<typename T>
class Outer : public anyClass<T>
{
public:
   using value_t = T;
   class Inner
   {
      virtual void foo(Outer<T>::value_t);
   };
};

template<typename T>
class specializer : protected Outer<T>::Inner
{
   virtual void foo(T x) override 
   {
       meow(x);
   }
};
```

I wonder how this would help you to change the behavior in `Outer` or `anyClass` because you have not shown code which shows where and how `Inner` is actually used. Without that, it's just guessing.

I have the feeling that what you are actually trying to achieve is to pass a function (or Strategy?) to you `Outer` class, represented by `Inner` in your code. That would be better done by passing it as a template argument.

```
template<typename T>
class anyClass {};

template<typename T, typename Inner = meow<T>>
class Outer : public anyClass<T>
{
public:
   using value_t = T;

   // somewhere in your code
   Inner i;
   i.meow( any_value );
};
```

You can also pass a `std::function` to the constructor.
    template
    class anyClass {};

```
template<typename T>
class Outer : public anyClass<T>
{
public:
   using value_t = T;

   Outer( std::function<void (value_t)> inner);

   // somewhere in your code
   i.meow( any_value );

   std::function<void (value_t)> i;
};
```

Comment: That would work. But currently i can't change the type for many reasons. I try to solve these reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Originally I simplyfied a little bit to much. 
Here is the compileable example of my problem: http://ideone.com/9U7J1a
I removed all unconducive code. I know the design is horrible but i have no influence on it.

```
class bar {};
class string {};

template<typename _T>
class ModelContainer 
{
    public:
    using value_type = _T;

   class Delegate {
     public:
       virtual void foo( value_type value);
   }; 
};

template< typename... _Ts >
class ModelManager__AbstractBase : protected ModelContainer< _Ts >...
{
public:
  class Delegate : public ModelContainer< _Ts >::Delegate... {
  public:
    virtual ~Delegate( ) = default;
  };
};


using ModelManager__Base = ModelManager__AbstractBase<
    int,
    float,
    string,
    bar
>;

class ModelManager : public ModelManager__Base {
    /* Some functions */
};

class spezializer : ModelManager::Delegate
{
    public:
    virtual ~spezializer() = default;
        //Uncommend to see my error  
       // virtual void foo( value_type value) override // << value_type unknown
       // {/* Calling everytime the same method, no matter which value_type*/}
};
```

Comment: Just tried to use the code and instantiated a `ModelManager::Delegate`. It does not compile.

Comment: Added missing `public` (see edit). Now, when I try to call `d.foo(s)` with a `std::string` `s`, I get a compiler error that the call to foo is ambiguous.

Comment: Also, this should be part of the question. Chances for good answers will be much higher if you provide examples which are minimal but complete and actually compile. As it is now, many people will just not try to answer the question.

Comment: You have to instantiat only spezializer and work with him. The rest is necessary for other parts of the application. 
With the adding public i could instantiate spezializer. Just the Foo method is left.

Comment: No, the following snippet will not compile: `spezializer d;
  std::string s;
  d.foo(s);` with an ambiguous error.

Comment: Exactly that is my problem. which i need to solve. Prefered without template spezializer

Comment: Your program is ambiguous. You either have to add using declarations or define the functions. There is nothing you can do. Well, you have a good reason to change the design.